# Why is the voltage across high impedance indeterminate?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, floating, high-impedance

The analog pins on my Arduino read sporadic values when unconnected, and my multimeter (set to VDC) shows random values when there's no connection between the probes. If I connect the analog pins on the Arduino to GND or if the multimeter's probes touch each other, each reads 0.

The Wikipedia page [High impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_impedance) doesn't explain *why* this happens (or I'm not seeing it).

I'm still a beginner at electronics, so a simple explanation (e.g. using Ohm's law) would be appreciated.

Comment: It's more complex than just an ohm's-law explanation. Do you understand that electric fields permeate from the wiring in your walls? Do you understand how these fields can be manipulated by impedances?

Comment: @Andy Roughly, yeah. I know that current flowing through a wire creates an emf, and that pushes back on the current (creating impedance).

Comment: You are talking about resistance and ohms law stuff. That doesn't count when you come to analyse electric fields that surround wires up to many metres.

Comment: @Andy If you want, you can write an answer and I'll just research the parts I don't understand

Comment: I can't provide this: *a simple explanation (e.g. using Ohm's law)*

Comment: Simple explanation : your probes form an antenna into which electric fields, magnetic fields, and radio signals will all propagate with varying degrees of efficiency. The largest signals into a high impedance will usually be electric fields from AC mains wiring nearby.

Comment: @user_1818839 Why does the sensitivity to these fields/signals increase when the probes are separated?

Comment: it becomes a better antenna for those fields (eventually a dipole when the leads are stretched out with the meter in the middle) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna

Comment: I'm happy with that explanation. If you write an answer and maybe expand a little on it, I'll accept it. Thanks.